# How can I recreate the clickable image carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, elementor

My question is how can I recreate the image menu (actually I don't eve know what's the proper name) from this site: https://bacc.cc/ ? The one at the "Discover friends, family, and purpose" section. Is it possible with elementor only or JS is necessary?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to use a library than create your own. They could be using a WordPress plugin that uses it, but the slider they use is [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/)